# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined on my developer tools

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I use tabs to navigate tracker page then it show error  'Cannot read property 'split' of undefined' in my developer tools

heres my tracker.TS file

```
previousDay() {
    var result = new Date(this.currentDate.valueOf());
    result.setDate(result.getDate() - 1);
    this.currentDate = result;
}

nextDay() {
    var result = new Date(this.currentDate.valueOf());
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + 1);
    this.currentDate = result;  
}

getLogs() {
    if(this.logs1 != null){
      return this.logs1.filter(checkDate, this);
    }

    function checkDate(log) {
      var logDate = new Date(log.date);
      return (logDate.getDate() == this.currentDate.getDate() && logDate.getMonth() == this.currentDate.getMonth() && logDate.getFullYear() == this.currentDate.getFullYear());
    }       
}
```

I expect it will cause from array or its have same object with my another TS file

Comment: This error is not related to this page. But the amount on which the split takes place is undefined

Comment: Yes, there is no call to split here.